# How to disable listbox item underlined when ALT key is pressed in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a Listbox with some string and int items. When ALT key is pressed the list items are unlined. I have set in `ContentPresenter` style like this, `RecognizesAccessKey="False"`. But it is not working. Please anyone suggest me to fix this. The Listbox values are like this, T1_1.

**MainWindow**

```
                                 <ListBox
                                    x:Name="dropListBox"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"

                                    AllowDrop="True"
                                    Background="#F8F8F8"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding DetailsCollection}"
                                    Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}">


                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}">
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>

                                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Image
                                                                Grid.Column="0"
                                                                Width="23"
                                                                Height="23"
                                                                Source="{Binding State, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource IntToImageSourceConverter}}" />
                                                            <Label
                                                                Grid.Column="1"
                                                                Content="{Binding Name}"
                                                                FontSize="12" />
                                                            <Label
                                                                Grid.Column="2"
                                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                                                                Content="{Binding CurrentValue}"
                                                                FontSize="12" />
                                                        </Grid>

                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                                </ListBox>
```

Comment: Yo should provide some more details about your `Listbox` and your code, otherwise it can be hard to help you

Comment: @IlVic, Please see my updated code and suggest me where I have done mistake or what I have to implement.

Comment: I have changed the ListBox Datatemplate Label to TextBlock. So the problem is solved.

Comment: Great! I guess it is the easiest solution!